# Mutli-category one-hot encoding to pivot-table

Tags: python, pandas, categories, categorical-data

I've got some data that is mostly made up of one hot encoded categorical data. I'd like to be able to demonstrate the co-occurence of the categories but I can't quite work out how to reshape it or count it. My main issue is that though I have unique cases, the categories are non exclusive meaning that each case may be categorised, in this example, with multiple countries, and with multiple issues.

```
case_id country.france  country.germany issue.water issue.health    issue.poverty
    0           0           1              1            0               1
    1           1           1              0            1               1
    2           1           1              0            1               1
    3           1           0              1            1               1
```

Desired output - a pivot table showing counts of co-occurence between the countries categories, and the issue categories:

```
                    issue.water issue.health    issue.poverty
country.france          1             3               3
country.germany         1             2               3
```

I've attempted reshaping my data so that my data looks more like...

```
case_id   country   issue
0        germany    water
0        germany    poverty
1        france     health
1        france     poverty
2        france     health
2        france     poverty
2        germany    health
2        germany    poverty
3        france     water
3        france     health
3        france     poverty
```

but I am unclear how I would turn this into the desired output, or if this is the correct way to handle cases with multiple categorisations. I have code but it's all been about the reshaping so far and I'm uncertain whether I should aim to reshape before I know whether I am taking the right approach in handling the multiple categories per case.

Any help getting my head around this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you reshape your `df`

```
pd.crosstab(df.country,df.issue)
Out[306]: 
issue    health  poverty  water
country                        
france        3        3      1
germany       1        2      1
```

Or more involved get the result from your df1, using  `wide_to_long`

```
newdf=pd.wide_to_long(df1,['issue'],i='case_id',j='issueid',suffix='\\w+',sep='.').set_index('issue',append=True).sum(level=[1,2]).query('issue==1')
newdf.reset_index(level=1,drop=True).T
Out[326]: 
issueid          water  health  poverty
country.france       1       3        3
country.germany      1       2        3
```

Comment: In the end I went for a different approach as my actual use case was a bit different from the simpler one I showed here.. . but this was the answer that helped me think it through better, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On your reshaped dataframe (if `df`), may be you can try as below:

```
p = pd.pivot_table(df, index='country', columns='issue', aggfunc="count")
# setting column names
p.columns = [c.replace('case_id', 'issue.')for c in map("".join, p.columns)]
```